# Set margin, the space between the text and the border of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

The margin would be the space between the text and the border of a cell.

Thus when autofitting a row height, the `AutoFit` function would consider `text_height + bottom_margin + top_margin` as cell height (similar behavior for columns with `left_margin` and `right_margin`).

Is there any property/function in Excel, available in VBA, to control the margin around text inside a cell?

Comment: Alignment can change the "margin" around text but this doesn't seem to be what you're getting at. I don't think this exists.

Comment: There's no cell "Margin" property.  Best you could might be to center the content then add a "margin" by resizing after autofitting

Comment: @TimWilliams Ok, that answers the question, thank you for the info !
Autofit reduces too much the space between the text and cell border, which makes it uneasy to read. I'll try to create a macro to resize row height based on the number of lines of the wraped text in the cell.

Comment: For anyone interested, here is workaround code:
```Range.Rows.AutoFit \
For Each row in Range.Rows \
row.RowHeight = ratio * row.RowHeight \
Next row```